# Fetch value from database after selecting multiple dropdowns

Tags: php, ajax, dropdown

I've been trying to fix this since yesterday and until now I'm still working on it. Can you please how to fetch value after selecting in 2 dropdown menus? Like for example, after selecting 5:30 AM the next dropdown will fetch the branch with a departure time of 5:30 AM. Then after selecting the branch dropdown, the third dropdown will fetch all the bus number base from the branch and the time that was selected. Then the fourth dropdown which is seat numbers will automatically showed up except for the numbers that was already selected in that bus. I already tried searching here and I still can't get the correct results.

Code:

```
<label id="label" for="schdtime">Schedule  Time</label>
<select id="schdtime" name="schdtime" style="margin-right: 15px;">
     <option value="5:30 AM">5:30 AM</option>
     <option value="7:30 AM">7:30 AM</option>
     <option value="9:30 AM">9:30 AM</option>
     <option value="11:30 AM">11:30 AM</option>
     <option value="12:30 PM">12:30 PM</option>
     <option value="1:30 PM">1:30 PM</option>
     <option value="3:30 PM">3:30 PM</option>
     <option value="5:00 PM">5:00 PM</option>
</select>

<label id="label" for="brnch">Route</label><br>
<select id="brnch" name="brnch">
     <option disabled="disabled value="">From</option>
</select>
```

Bus Number

Select Bus Number

```
<label id="label">Seat Number</label>
<select id="seatnum" name="seatnum" style="width: 100px;">
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
     <option value="5">5</option>
     <option value="6">6</option>
     <option value="7">7</option>
     <option value="8">8</option>
     <option value="9">9</option>
     <option value="10">10</option>
     <option value="11">11</option>
     <option value="12">12</option>
     <option value="13">13</option>
     <option value="14">14</option>
     <option value="15">15</option>
</select>
```

This is my ajax.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Change in continent dropdown list will trigger this function and
  //generate dropdown options for county dropdown
   $(document).on('change','#schdtime', function() {
    var schdtime = $(this).val();
    if(schdtime != "") {
      $.ajax({
        url:"get_data.php",
        type:'POST',
        data:{schdtime:schdtime},
        success:function(response) {
          //var resp = $.trim(response);
          if(response != '') {
            $("#brnch").removeAttr('disabled','disabled').html(response);
            $("").attr('disabled','disabled').html("<option value=''>Choose</option>");
          } else {
            $("#area, #busnum, #seatnum").attr('disabled','disabled').html("<option value=''>Choose</option>");
          }
        }
      });
    } else {
      $("#area, #busnum, #seatnum").attr('disabled','disabled').html("<option value=''>Choose</option>");
    }
  });
  $(document).on('change','#brnch', function() {
    var brnch = $(this).val();
    if(brnch != "") {
      $.ajax({
        url:"get_data.php",
        type:'POST',
        data:{brnch:brnch},
        success:function(response) {
          //var resp = $.trim(response);
          if(response != '') {
            $("#area").removeAttr('disabled','disabled').html(response);
            $("#seatnum").attr('disabled','disabled').html("<option value=''>Choose</option>");
          } else {
            $("#area, #busnum, #seatnum").attr('disabled','disabled').html("<option value=''>Choose</option>");
          }
        }
      });
    } 
    else 
    {
      $("#area, #busnum, #seatnum").attr('disabled','disabled').html("<option value=''>Choose</option>");
    }
    });
    $(document).on('change','#brnch','#schdtime', function() {
    var branch = $(this).val();
    if(brnch != "") {
      $.ajax({
        url:"get_data.php",
        type:'POST',
        data:{branch:branch},
        success:function(response) {
          //var resp = $.trim(response);
          if(response != '') {
            $("#busnum, #seatnum").removeAttr('disabled','disabled').html(response);
            $("").attr('disabled','disabled').html("<option value=''>Choose</option>");
          } else {
            $("#area, #busnum, #seatnum").attr('disabled','disabled').html("<option value=''>Choose</option>");
          }
        }
      });
    } else {
      $("#area, #busnum, #seatnum").attr('disabled','disabled').html("<option value=''>Choose</option>");
    }
  });
  //Change in coutry dropdown list will trigger this function and
  //generate dropdown options for state dropdown
  $(document).on('change','#busnum', function() {
    var busnum = $(this).val();
    if(busnum != "") {
      $.ajax({
        url:"get_data.php",
        type:'POST',
        data:{busnum:busnum},
        success:function(response) {
          //var resp = $.trim(response);
          if(response != '') {
            $("$seatnum").removeAttr('disabled','disabled').html(response);
            $("").attr('disabled','disabled').html("<option value=''>Choose</option>");
          }
          else $("#seatnum").attr('disabled','disabled').html("<option value=''>Choose</option>");
        }
      });
    } else {
      $("#seatnum").attr('disabled','disabled').html("<option value=''>Choose</option>");
    }
  });
});
```

Then this for the get_data.php:

```
<?php include('includes/connection.php');?>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['schdtime'])) 
{
  $qry1 = "SELECT * FROM branch";
  $res = mysqli_query($conn, $qry1);
  if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) 
  {
    echo '<option value="">Choose</option>';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($res)) 
    {
      echo '<option value="'.$row->Br_Name.'">'.$row->Br_Name.'</option>';
    }
  } 
  else 
  {
    echo '<option value="">To be added</option>';
  }
} 


if (isset($_POST['brnch'])) 
{
  $brnch = $_POST['brnch'];
  
  $qry2 = "SELECT * FROM area WHERE Ar_Cty_Mncpl ='".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$brnch)."' OR Ar_Descript = 'Allen'";
  $res = mysqli_query($conn, $qry2);
  if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) 
  {
    echo '<option value="">Choose</option>';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($res)) 
    {
      echo '<option value="'.$row->Ar_Descript.'">'.$row->Ar_Descript.'</option>';
    }
  } 
  else 
  {
    echo '<option value="">To be added</option>';
  }
}


if(isset($_POST['branch'])) 
{
  /*$schdtime = $_POST['schdtime'];*/
  $branch = $_POST['branch'];
  $qry2 = "SELECT * FROM bus WHERE Bus_Branch = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$branch)."'";
  $res = mysqli_query($conn, $qry2);
  if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) 
  {
    echo '<option value="">Choose</option>';
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($res)) 
     {
       $spc = ' ';
        echo '<option value="'.$row->Bus_Plate_Number.'">'.$row->Bus_Plate_Number. $spc .$row->Bus_Class.'</option>';
     }
   } else 
   {
       echo '<option value="">No available bus</option>';
   }
}
```

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should alway use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: At what stage does your code stop working as expected? Does it do anything you want correctly? Are you seeing errors in the console or php logs? Is it the Javascript, the PHP or the sql queries that are causing issue?

Comment: You have shown 3 dropdown menus but `"Then the fourth dropdown which is seat numbers"` suggests that there is one not shown... is that `area` and where in the sequence is it?

Comment: oh sorry I wasn't able to include the fourth dropdown. but I want it to be something where after selecting the bus number, It will store the available seat numbers of that bus.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a way to greatly simplify the code that you have to accomplish what I think the stated goal is. With some minor tweaks to the HTML it should be possible to use a single function to process the `change` event for all `select` menus. I'll admit to get a little boggle eyed whilst looking at the Javascript above trying to figure what element name and what menu and what sql was which and what so I may have made a mistook but the following does, I think, show how you can accomplish the goal of chained `select` menus and fetching content from the database depending on what the user selects. Gone though is the jQuery in favour of the `fetch` api and because it is a demo it has the PHP on the same page rather than the separate `get_data.php`...

Notice that 3 of the 4 `select` menus have a dataset attribute called `data-dependent`. This holds the name of the NEXT dropdown to target with new content. The 4th dropdown does not have this attribute as it is the final one in the chain so processing can stop there or start again if a new option is selected from earlier in the chain.

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset(
        $_POST['name'],
        $_POST['value']
    )){
        ob_clean();
        /* 
            send dummy data back to emulate processing in get_data.php
            in real code you will obtain values by doing db search but
            with Prepared Statements rather than embedded variables!!!
            
            
            Your `get_data` script might be more like this perhaps:
            
            
            
            $args=$_POST['value'];
            
            switch( $_POST['name'] ){
                case 'schdtime':    #no prepared statement needed for this...
                    $sql='SELECT `Br_Name` as `field` FROM `branch`';
                    $args=false;
                break;
                
                case 'area':
                    $sql='SELECT `Ar_Descript` as `field` FROM `area` WHERE `Ar_Cty_Mncpl`=?';
                break;
                
                case 'branch':
                    $sql='SELECT `Bus_Plate_Number` as `field` FROM `bus` WHERE `Bus_Branch`=?';
                break;
            }
            
            
            if( $args ){
                $stmt=$conn->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->bind_params('s',$args);
                $stmt->execute();
                $res=$stmt->get_result();
                while( $rs=$res->fetch_object() ) printf('<option>%s',$rs->field );
            }else{
                $res=$conn->query($sql);
                while( $rs=$res->fetch_object() ) printf('<option>%s',$rs->field );
            }
            
            ##... this is completely untested ...##
            
            
            
            
            The below is ONLY to provide content for the NEXT select menu...
        */
        
        for( $i=1; $i <= 10; $i++ )printf('<option>%s - %s - %s', $_POST['name'], $_POST['value'], $i );
        exit();
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
        
        
            <label>Schedule  Time
                <select class='usrselect' name='schdtime' data-dependent='area'>
                    <option disabled selected hidden>Time...
                    <option>5:30 AM
                    <option>7:30 AM
                    <option>9:30 AM
                    <option>11:30 AM
                    <option>12:30 PM
                    <option>1:30 PM
                    <option>3:30 PM
                    <option>5:00 PM
                </select>
            </label>

            <label>Area
                <select class='usrselect' name='area' data-dependent='branch' disabled>
                    <option disabled selected hidden>Area...
                </select>
            </label>
            
            <label>Route
                <select class='usrselect' name='branch' data-dependent='seatnum' disabled>
                    <option disabled selected hidden>From...
                </select>
            </label>

            <label>Seat Number
                <select class='usrselect' name='seatnum' disabled>
                    <option disabled selected hidden>Seat...
                    <option>1
                    <option>2
                    <option>3
                    <option>4
                    <option>5
                    <option>6
                    <option>7
                    <option>8
                    <option>9
                    <option>10
                    <option>11
                    <option>12
                    <option>13
                    <option>14
                    <option>15
                </select>
            </label>
        </form>
    
        <script>
            const q=(e,n=document)=>n.querySelector(e);
            const qa=(e,n=document)=>n.querySelectorAll(e);
            const url=location.href; // 'get_data.php'
            
            
            const changehandler=function(e){
                let dependent=this.dataset.dependent;
                
                if( dependent ){
                    /*
                        prepare payload to send to server
                        as a name & value. This makes it
                        easier in PHP to process as these
                        remain consistent for each request.
                    */
                    let fd=new FormData();
                        fd.set('name',this.name);
                        fd.set('value',this.value);
                    
                    /*
                        Find where in the sequence this dropdown is
                        - empty and disable those that follow in 
                        readiness for the callback to populate content
                    */
                    let col=[...qa('select.usrselect')];
                    let index=col.indexOf( this );
                    for( let i=index + 1; i < col.length; i++ ){
                        col[i].innerHTML='';
                        col[i].disabled=true;
                    }
                    
                    
                    /*
                        send the ajax request and use the response 
                        data to populate the `dependent` menu OR 
                        proceed to next stage.
                    */
                    fetch( url, { method:'post',body:fd })
                        .then(r=>r.text())
                        .then(text=>{
                            let menu=q('select[ name="'+dependent+'" ]');
                                menu.innerHTML=text;
                                menu.disabled=false;
                        })      
                }else{
                    /* The last stage.... */
                    alert( 'The user has selected from ALL dropdowns\n\n' + this.value )
                }
            };
            
            
            
            
            
            qa('select.usrselect').forEach(sel=>sel.addEventListener('change',changehandler));
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'll try this right away

Comment: I already tried it but after selecting in schdtime, there's no data inside

Comment: Please explain what that means. What did you try? At what point does it fail? Is it the PHP that you are referring to? The mechanism above might not be an exact fit because, to be honest, I was more than a little confused with the names of elements and which select came first as you show only 3 of 4. Please clarify

Comment: I mean, I tried all your codes, but I changed the data-dependant in schdtime to 'branch' instead of 'area' since after selecting the time dropdown, the branch is the next dropdown to be show, followed by area, then busnum, then the last dropdown is the seatnum.

Comment: Ok so the sequence is different - like you say change the `dependent` attribute. It was not at all clear what the sequence was supposed to be. I can not test this as I do not have the database or data... the mechanism above though works but without the database/data I can not really do more